# onclick="validateForm();return false"?

Tags: javascript, html

I came across some code involving a submit button, whose onclick attribute is: onclick="validateForm();return false". For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>form</title>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value; 
    if (name.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Name must be filled out!";  
    }
    else
        document.myForm.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" style="color:red"></div><br>
<form name="myForm" action="formHandler.jsp" method="post" target="_blank">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();return false"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't see any difference even if I remove return false in the above example. The return false does not stop the form from submitting as long as the text field is entered. So, what's the purpose of using "return false" immediately after the form is submitted by document.myForm.submit()?

Comment: Probably moved the listener from the form to the button, which is a dumb idea since the form can be submitted without clicking the button, so avoiding the button's validation. Submitting by script bypasses the submit listener.

Comment: What happens when it is invalid and you click the button? I bet it does not behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

It’s for when the form *isn’t* submitted by `document.myForm.submit()`, i.e. in the error case. A better way to write it would probably be to have `validateForm` control the return value:

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value; 
    if (name.trim() == "") {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Name must be filled out!";
        // Error; cancel the form submission
        return false;
    }

    // Just let the browser continue submitting; no need to .submit()
    return true;
}
```

and

```
<form name="myForm" action="formHandler.jsp" method="post" target="_blank"
      onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> <br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: The `return true` statement is redundant. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: I don’t like multi-type functions, though!

Comment: Consider (where *this* is the form) `var isValid = /\w/.test(this.fname.value); if (!isValid) {/* do stuff if false */} return isValid;` separates concerns and there's only one return statement. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: That doesn’t lend itself to validating multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Check Working example :

```js
function validateform(){  
var name=document.myform.name.value;  
var password=document.myform.password.value;  
  
if (name==null || name==""){  
  alert("Name can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}else if(password.length<6){  
  alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");  
  return false;  
  }  
}
```

```html
  
  
<form name="myform" method="post" action="http://www.javatpoint.com/javascriptpages/valid.jsp" onsubmit="return validateform()" >  
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>  
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="register">  
</form>
```